# Refer to a range and highlighting it using cells and range using a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refer to a range and then select it and then perform some actions on it.

I set variable x to value of 1 and used the following reference statement:

```
Range(cells(x, 1), cells(x, 10)).select
```

but this did not work,, the range hasn't been selected by this statement

how to do that in VBA?

Comment: Please add the code that you have worked upon, it will be much easier to resolve, rather than creating one from scratch.

Comment: This should work - although your `select` is in lower case, which makes me think you did not copy the string from your editor (both `cells` and `select` would automatically become upper case). What did you _really_ have in your code? Are you sure this statement was executed, and nothing else? Could it be that `cells` are referring to a different worksheet than you think?

Comment: it is not from a code, it is just I've been playing around with VBA and encountered this problem, this statement is similar to one I've written and executed but did not work,,, yes I did not copy it from VBE, I do not remember exactly what the code I've written but the idea is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually unsafe to use `Cells` without a qualifier - you don't know at run time what worksheet it will refer to.  Try:

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
x = 5
Set r1 = sh.Cells(x, 1)
Set r2 = sh.Cells(x, 10)
Range(r1, r2).Select
```

As you can see, I added a reference to a particular sheet in a particular workbook. Works every time for me.

Comment: Thank you Sir, that contained new ideas to me :)